# Connect EKS cluster using boto3 and then need to drain a particular node

Tags: amazon-eks

I have a scenario,
1) I need to connect a EKS cluster using boto3
2) then, need to drain a particular node using boto3

any one have solution for this?

Comment: just curious what have you tried ?

Comment: Hi @sayboras,  I am looking a solution at https://medium.com/@alejandro.millan.frias/managing-kubernetes-from-aws-lambda-7922c3546249. but there no option(API) to drain in that article.